# Nested Derivative

Tags: evaluation

These two expressions are mathematically the same, but when substituting with the same rule, yield different results. What is happening?

```
Derivative[1][Derivative[1][x][t]][t] == 5 t + 3 x[t] /. 
  {x -> Function[{t}, 1/3 (-5 t + Derivative[1][Derivative[1][x][t]][t])]}

D[x[t], t, t] == 5 t + 3 x[t] /. 
  {x -> Function[{t}, 1/3 (-5 t + Derivative[1][Derivative[1][x][t]][t])]}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct notation for a double derivative is `Derivative[1][ Derivative[1][x] ][t]`, not `Derivative[1][ Derivative[1][x][t] ][t]`.  Note the difference between a function `f` and its value at `t`: `f[t]`.  `Derivative[1][x]` represents a function.  `Derivative[1][x][t]` represents  its value at `t`.

`Derivative` needs to be used like this: `Derivative[k][f]` where `k` is a number and `f` is a function.  In place of `f` you had `Derivative[1][x][t]` which is not a function, but a value of the function at `t`.

The simpler notation for the second derivative is `Derivative[2][x]`.

Comment: Thank you, I think I still have a lot to learn.